# Many population layer mongose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a problem finding a solution to populate a filed populated(the number of populate unknowen)

```
 export const FilesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    children: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Files',
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

it represent a structure of file that can be a file or a folder.
a folder can contient another folder and another folder with files
the number of population are unknowen . any help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution
Say you have a user schema which keeps track of the user's friends.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
friends: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

Populate lets you get a list of a user's friends, but what if you also wanted a user's friends of friends? Specify the populate option to tell mongoose to populate the friends array of all the user's friends:

```
User.
findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
populate({
path: 'friends',
// Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
populate: { path: 'friends' }
});
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate